# Kotlin:java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.app.datastorepreferences.MyViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting this error

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.app.datastorepreferences.MyViewModel
at com.app.datastorepreferences.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.app.datastorepreferences.MyViewModel> has no zero argument constructor

viewmodel

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
val kotlinDataStore = KotlinDataStore(application)

val readFromDataStore = kotlinDataStore.readPreferences.asLiveData()
fun sendName(name: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    kotlinDataStore.writeToDataStore(name)
 }
}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.readFromDataStore.observe(this, {myNAME ->
        textView.text = myNAME.toString()
    })
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val name = edit_text.text.toString()
        viewModel.sendName(name)
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
 // ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Preferences DataStore
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

Comment: Can u share snippet from ViewModelProvider class as well?

Comment: @ShailyGarg I'm extending android view model not view model